# Probability and coin toss

Tags: probability

I know that the average amount of coin tosses we need to do before we get H is 2, before we get HH is 6, and so on.   but what does average means?
And if I have an infinite sequnce of coin tosses, does it mean that as k gets bigger, the amount of coin tosses until I got kH (HH...H k times) gets closer to the averge amount of tosses until I get kH?
Is it true for every sequnce of coin tosses?

Answer (score 0):

Here "average" stands for "expected value".

For the second part of your question, the statement as you write it is not correct. Generally expected value value doesn't apply to each particular sequence but to a large number of sequences. The right intuition would be:

Repeat the following experiment $H$ : generate a sequence of coin tosses as long as necessary until you get kH and note $f(H)$ the number of tosses until you got it.

For $n$ repetitions of the experiment $H$, the average value of sequence length is $\bar{f}(n)=mean\{f(H_k), k\in\{0,...,n\}\}$.

Then $\bar{f}(n)$ tends toward the average (i.e. expected value) amount of tosses when $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: so is the statement you wrote correct?

Comment: The way I formulated it, yes it is correct (hopefully!). That's the law of large numbers.

Comment: so in every infinite set of experiments, some must be below the expected value and some must be above it?

Comment: Yes, that would be right (but for the very special case of experiments of variance zero).

Comment: thank you, your answer helped me a lot. apparently I was trying to prove a wrong conjecture.

Comment: Does it mean that if I have infinitely many infinite sequences of coin tosses, then at least one of those sequences has H in the first two tosses? because  your statement proves it, but it doesn't sounds so true for me.

Comment: If your sequences are independant from each others (in particular, if you don't reject on purpose all sequences that do not start by TT), the probabilty of never having a H in the first two tosses is zero.

Comment: can you please formulate "independent sequences"?

Comment: If you don't mind I'd rather send you there: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_%28probability_theory%29 ...

Comment: thank you, but when you said "if your sequences are independent from each others", what events did you mean that are independent?

Comment: Each toss in teh first sequence is independant from each toss in the second sequence, and so on...

Comment: Is there any infinite sequence of coin tosses which contains only T?

Comment: There is one, yes. But the probability of it occuring is 0.

Comment: well, than I can change my first question, and ask this: